# Regex line by line over large string

Tags: python, regex, loops

I have a lot of rows like below in a file:

```
{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","age":30}
{"first_name":"Tim","last_name":"Johnson","age":34}
```

I first tried importing this as a dictionary with the json module so I could just print the values of the keys.  The problem is some of the lines are missing the right curly bracket or have other issues and the fields aren't in the same order per line.  That is preventing the import.

So now I am trying to do this with a regex.  I have this:

```
fo = open("c:\\newgoodtestsample.txt", "r")
x = fo.read()
match1 = re.search('first_name"(.*?)"(.*?)"', x) 
if match1:
    print match1.group(2)
```

That returns the value of just the name.  I would like to be able to return other fields as well.  This worked in a regex tester but I can't get it to work in my code:

```
(first_name|last_name|age)"(.*?)"(.*?)"
```

Lastly, once that is figured out, I need to read each line in the file (not just the first one) and print the requested regex data from each line into a file.  I have tried inserting a for loop but I keep getting the first line repeated over and over so I must be inserting it incorrectly.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please edit your post with examples of each different issues you encounter in the file?

Comment: The issues that are preventing me from importing it with the JSON module or the errors when trying to do the bottom regex?

Comment: All that is different from the two first rows you write, to view the different cases. I ask that because you write "or have other issues" in your post.

Comment: In the real file there are around 50 keys/values and each row is separated by a new line.  There are over 13,000 rows.  When I tried to import the file with the JSON module it worked on the first 100 rows and I could call the keys/values.  However, when trying to do the 13k row file I kept getting errors.  I found one of the rows was missing a right curly brace.  I did a count for how many right curly braces were in the file and it is around 1000 short.  I can't really write a script to add them because the last key/value changes in each row as they aren't in a specific order.

Comment: I am only assuming there could be other issues aside from the right curly braces missing on 1000 of the rows.  It could only be that though and I don't know how I would add them since the fields aren't in order so I don't know what the last one will always be.

Comment: If I understand well, You have 1 record (with different fields) by line, thus the closing curly brackets must be (when it is not missing) the last character of the line?

Comment: You could try using a regex replace to fix the file, then import it using a JSON parser. Have you tried replacing newlines with right curly brace -> newline?

Comment: Yes, there are 13k records with different fields each on a new line.  I opened the file in notepad++ and at the end of each line it shows CR LF.  So I guess I could try to replace the \r\n with }\r\n.  That is a good idea.  thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do what you want, the regex should give you back as matching groups all the value fields from the JSON (although not the keywords under which those values are stored).

I also encourage you to use the `with` context manager as that will close the file handle automatically after all lines have been read, which is easily done just with a for loop.

```
with open("c:\\newgoodtestsample.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        result = re.findallr'"(\w*?)":"?(\w*)"?', line) 
        d = {k:v for k,v in re.findall(r'"(\w*?)":"?(\w*)"?', line)}
        if 'first_name' in d:
            # print first_name into file
        else:
            # print empty first_name field
```

Comment: Thanks Matti.  So I am able to print out all of the first names with this for example.  The only issue is some of the rows don't have a first name.  How can I get your code to print a "none" or something like that if the first_name field is missing?

Comment: I ultimately will be putting each field as a column in a spreadsheet so I don't want them to get out of order if a field is missing.

Comment: nm, I got it to work with an else statement.  I wanted to make sure I can use your method if I can't end up importing the json correctly into a dictionary.  thx!

Comment: @Christopher see updated code above. I changed it to use `findall` and turn the found list of tuples into a dictionary so that you can control which keys are present and which arent.